# Displaying Popup window on canvas in view class

Tags: android, canvas, android-view, android-popupwindow

I have a view class that draws different colored circles onto the canvas.

I want to display a popup window near the circle when the circle is clicked to display the color of the circle. Right now I am facing problem trying to create the popup window.

Most of the tutorials does the popup window on activity class thus i could not find a example to reference to.

My code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();

                   // Open popup window
                       for(int i =0; i < circles.size(); i++){
            if (buttonClick == true && circles.get(i).contains(x, y)) {

                                   View view = inflate(getContext(),R.layout.popup_layout, null); 
                PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(view);
    popup.showAtLocation(MainActivity.returnView(), Gravity.LEFT, (int)x, (int)y);

                        }
                           } 
             break;
}
```

Popup window xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">
 <LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:layout_margin="1dp"
     android:background="@android:color/WHITE">
     >
     <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:layout_margin="20dp">
      <TextView
           android:id="@+id/ColorTV"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Insert Text here" />
      <Button
          android:id="@+id/dismissbtn"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Dismiss" />
      </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PopupWindow`. Use `PopupWindow#showAtLocation (View parent, int gravity, int x, int y)` method to put your popup where you want it, using your view itself as the parent.

So, inside your `View`'s onTouchEvent, you could have:

```
View view = inflate(R.layout.my_popup_view, null); // however you'll inflate your view
PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(view, 300, 300, true);
popup.showAtLocation(this, Gravity.LEFT, x, y);
```

or something similar.

Comment: the R.layout.my_popup_view refers to layout of my popup window right? or my view layout?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried out but it doesn't work:( i have included the xml file of my popup window above and your suggestion. adding on, i dont see any errors in my program when the codes above is running.

Comment: Try adding a width and height (and focusable) parameter to the PopupWindow's constructor. I updated the answer to reflect this. Also, try using getRawX() and getRawY() instead of getX() and getY().